# Can an Admin get an Access Token for a specific consumer in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I get as an Admin Access tokens in behalf of the consumers without consumers having to type the password?

In other words, I'm looking for a way to automatically login consumers in my application without them having to type the passwords.

Other platforms allow sign in with JWT to implement this.

How can an admin "impersonate" a consumer and automatically log the consumer?

Thank you!

Comment: Azure B2C ROPC flow allows you to set the password in code. You don't need to type the password. Let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: Hi @AllenWu, thank you for your answer. Documentation states ROPC should be only used client-side. And the idea is that admins don't know the password of the consumers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample here which does such an impersonation:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/impersonation

Comment: it still requires a CS Login. Won't work in a server scenario

Comment: You can not use any non interactive method to impersonate a user on your own server.